# Como puedo saber que rol tiene un usuario determinado si estoy utilizando Entrust en laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando el paquete Entrust para gestionar roles en laravel y nejcesito saber como puedo una ves que todos los roles esten creados y los usuarios y las relaciones entre estos como si tengo un usuario guardado en una variable saber el rol que le corresponde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo tendras un rol para cada usuario

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma

```
$usuario->roles()->first()->name
```

Si tendras mas de un rol por usuario tendras que hacerlo  asi

```
$usuario->roles()->get()
```

Comment: Ese no es mi problema, mira te explico mejor, Yo quiero que en una tabla donde muestro los datos de los usuarios me salga que rol tienen, desde el controlador mando un arreglo con la consulta de todos los usuarios luego en la vista utilizo un @foreach($users as  $user) para mostrar cada una de las filas de la tabla y necesito saber si puedo con el valor de la variable $user puedo saver su rol dinamicamente.

Comment: Debes hacerlo de esta forma entonces
$user->roles()->first()->name para obtener solo el primero, y si quieres obtener mas de uno, pues le hace usuario->roles()->get()

Comment: Cuando pongo lo que me sugeriste me da ese error: "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_5-6\resources\views\users\table.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_5-6\resources\views\users\table.blade.php) ◀" pero cuando quito el ->name si em pone un arreglo con los datos del rol: {"id":2,"name":"editor","display_name":"Editor","description":"Personal de mantenimiento","created_at":"2018-03-21 11:44:14","updated_at":"2018-03-21 11:44:15","pivot":{"user_id":8,"role_id":2}} . Que me esta  pasando

Comment: Puede ser que algun usuario no esta con los roles correctos y al  llamar al name pues no existe, queda alguna fila de usuario vacia?

Comment: Si tenia dos filas vacias las elimine y funcionó gracias hermano

Comment: De nada, cualquier duda consulta